# Flag a line chart series if it is over another series

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets with about 10-20 graphs per sheet. every graph is of the same format witht the same series names. one series is called "forecast spendings" and the other is called "spendings should-be." I need to flag the chart when the forecast spendings line goes over the spendings shout-be line. I was thinking making a red dot on the given point(s).

I tried using a bunch of tricks with conditional foratting by making other data tables and manipulating the values but with no success.

VBA will probably be the solution. I've never used VBA on charts though so im not sure how to procede. I've been doing sone research but i dont know how to modify codes in accordance to my needs due to my inexperience with charts.

I think comparind an array of the 2 series would be the answer. this would then have to loop for each chart and then loof for each sheet.

I found this code that seems useable to me but i dont understant what is being referenced. I'm guessing this is assuming that htere is only one chart wiht one serie:

```
Dim chartIterator As Integer, pointIterator As Integer, _
    seriesArray() As Variant

For chartIterator = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    seriesArray =  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
                   chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values

    For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)             

       If seriesArray(pointIterator) >= 0 Then
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _  
           chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(146, 208, 80)
       Else
           ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
           chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _
           RGB(255, 0, 0)
       End If

    Next pointIterator

Next chartIterator
```

Please explain your answer so i can understand it and repeat it.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: When you say "goes over" do you mean "exceeds" or "covers/crosses"?

Comment: exceeds. When the Y values of one are greater that the Y valure of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work fine for me.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim co As ChartObject
    For Each co In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        CheckChart co.Chart
    Next co

End Sub

Sub CheckChart(cht As Chart)

    Dim s As Series, sForecast As Series, sShould As Series
    Dim i As Long

    'see if we can find the required series on this chart
    For Each s In cht.SeriesCollection
        Debug.Print s.Name
        If s.Name = "forecast spendings" Then Set sForecast = s
        If s.Name = "spendings should-be" Then Set sShould = s
    Next s

    'series located?
    If sShould Is Nothing Or sForecast Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "required series not found!"
    Else
        'found the series, so compare the point values
        'assumes same # of points in both lines
        '   and same start/end
        For i = 1 To sShould.Points.Count
            If sForecast.Values(i) > sShould.Values(i) Then
                'label point
                With sForecast.Points(i)
                    .HasDataLabel = True
                    .DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                    .DataLabel.Text = "!!!"
                    .DataLabel.Characters.Font.Color = vbRed
                End With

            End If
       Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this is gonna save me so much time. Thanks Tim! I hadnt thought about looping through another sub. The "if s.Name" part is what was blocking me. i didn't know how to do that. I also added a couple lines to erase past flags when rerunning the macro in case the forecast isnt over the should-be anymore. Thanks again for the help